# How to display timestamp format in edit form in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, date, datepicker

I am trying to write update function in laravel, and I am trying to get the old value in edit form, the text fields are easy to retrive back in the form, and also date fields is also working, but for the timestamp field, I coudn't able to get the old value.Please help me out.This simple date field is working.

```
  <input type="date" value="{{Carbon\Carbon::parse($package->start_date)->format('Y-m-d')}}" name="start_date">
```

But for the timestamp field, I tried many format, for example like

```
 <input type="datetime-local" value="{{Carbon\Carbon::parse($package->start_date)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')}}" name="start_date">
```

Comment: [Here is the solution.](http://jsfiddle.net/g7mvaosL/)

Comment: Its only for the normal date field, I want to get the date and time (timestamps).@SandOfVega

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `date` input type use `toDateString()` method, for `datetime-local` input type use `toDateTimeLocalString()` or `format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s')`